# Updating objects in Entity Framework is failing

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The following code updates `d1.AttemptedMatches` about 5% of the time.

I'm trying to figure out why and also how to fix it.

```
        [HttpGet("match")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetMatchup()
    {
        // Pick the deck with the least matches and pit it against a random deck, no mirror matches

        // use attempted matches to weed out decks that crash a lot.
        Deck d1 = db.Decks.OrderBy(t => t.AttemptedMatches).First();

        //Deck d2 = db.Decks.Where(t => t.Id != d1.Id).OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).First(); // this might generate an expensive query

        Deck d2 = db.Decks.FromSqlRaw(string.Format("SELECT * FROM mtgbattles.decks where id <> {0} ORDER by RAND() limit 1", d1.Id)).First();

        List<Deck> result = new List<Deck>();

        result.Add(d1);
        result.Add(d2);

        int a = MtgBattles.Util.Configs.matchSize;

        d1.AttemptedMatches += a;
        d2.AttemptedMatches += a;

        db.SaveChanges();
```

I have already attempted adding

```
db.Entry(d1).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I think I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: If you leave out the d2 parts, do you also get the problems about not updating?

Comment: That you are returning entities to the client is a bit of a concern. If Decks are passed back from any client to the server to be persisted, they will overwrite any values the DB may have been updated with. If you put a breakpoint after SaveChanges, does the Database value not get updated in some cases? That would be rather odd, but I suspect the issue may be more to do with later actions overwriting the DB with stale entities.

Comment: I could update the data successfully.Could you share the error message?Which line makes such error?